# WP acf, как вернуть н/д если поле не заполнено?

Tags: wordpress, acf

Как вернуть кастомное значение в типе поля number, плагин Advanced Custom Field
Если поле не заполнено или пустое, в записи выводиться через шорткод [acf field= "my_field"]

Вставляю в function.php код вида:

```
$value = get_field( "text_field" );
if( $value ) {
    echo $value;
} else {
    echo 'н/д';
}
```

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Но как сделать правильно?

Comment: У вас шорткод выводится в контенте?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы никак не можете избавиться от шоткода, то можно в `functions.php` добавить фильтр

```
add_filter( 'do_shortcode_tag', 'my_do_shortcode_acf', 10, 3 );
function my_do_shortcode_acf( $out, $tag, $atts ) {
    if ( 'acf' === $tag && isset( $atts['field'] ) && 'field_name' === $atts['field'] && empty( $out ) ) {
        $out = 'н/д';
    }

    return $out;
}
```

А код, который вы показали вы можеет вставить вместо шорткода в шаблон вашей php-страницы

Comment: А не подскажите ещё момент, как перечислить несколько полей? if ( 'acf' === $tag && isset( $atts['field'] ) && 'field_name1', 'field_name2'

Comment: Создайте массив ваших полей и используйте in_array